# What is the difference between std::__gcd and std::gcd?

Tags: c++, algorithm, greatest-common-divisor

[Many](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdgcd-c-inbuilt-function-finding-gcd/) [websites](https://codeforces.com/submissions/Madiyar) and [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52906184/why-gcd-is-throwing-error-in-macos-mojave) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248060/gcd-function-in-visual-studio-version-1-38-0) [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61128400/inbuilt-std-gcd-function-for-c-is-not-working-on-mac-os-xcode) [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981380/implementation-of-the-in-built-gcd-method-in-c) reference a function named `std::__gcd`. What’s the difference between this function and `std::gcd`?

Comment: Names beginning with `_` are reserved for the implementation: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Yes, that’s true, though some implementations will in turn export those names to programmers (see, for example, `__builtin_expect` or `__asm`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did some sleuthing on this. It looks like the `__gcd` function is a private helper function defined [in the libstdc++ implementation of the `<algorithm>` header (line 1503)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.4/a01347.html). It’s used internally only by the `std::rotate` function (line 1610). It was (probably) never intended to be used directly outside of the library implementation. Because it’s specific to libstdc++, trying to use this function through compilers other than g++ isn’t guaranteed to work. In that sense, you can think of the `std::__gcd` function as a (poorly documented) internal helper that’s only available with some C++ compilers.

(Fun fact: I was first alerted to the existence of `__gcd` by a now-deleted question here asking why it handled negative inputs inconsistently. Turns out it wasn’t really designed to handle negative numbers, since the libstdc++ implementation only uses it in cases where the inputs are nonnegative. It’s one of the risks of using an undocumented internal helper function!)

On the other hand, `std::gcd` is a standard C++ library function that was introduced in C++17. This means that any C++17-compliant compiler will support `std::gcd`, so it’s preferable to use this option if you have a C++17-compliant compiler.

For C++14 or lower, you can simply implement your own version GCD function. Euclid’s algorithm is very straightforward to code up and runs extremely quickly.